# How to aggregate array type in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

This is the example table

exampleTable:

```
   id | weeklyNumber |
   ---- -------------
   1  |  [2,5,9]     |
   ------------------
   2  |  [1,10,4]    |
```

The expected results should be the aggregation result of weeklyNumber array which is 
[3,15,13] (2+1, 5+10, 9+4)

I did not get idea how to do this.

----- update ----
In addition,
we have many rows of the below table
exampleTable:

```
   id | weeklyNumber | monthlyNumber
   ---- ------------- -------------
   1  |  [2,5,9]     | [20,50,90] 
   --------------------------------
   2  |  [1,10,4]    | [10,100,40]
```

the result should be [2/20 + 1/10, 5/50 + 10/100, 9/90 + 4/40]. How to do that?

Comment: The answer was updated to cover the second part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to use [ForEach](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/combinators/#agg-functions-combinator-foreach)-aggregate function combinator:

```sql
SELECT sumForEach(weeklyNumber)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 AS id,
        [2, 5, 9] AS weeklyNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS id,
        [1, 10, 4] AS weeklyNumber
)
/*
┌─sumForEach(weeklyNumber)─┐
│ [3,15,13]                │
└──────────────────────────┘
*/
```

---

In some cases could be used this query:

```sql
SELECT arrayReduce('sumForEach', groupArray(weeklyNumber))
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 AS id,
        [2, 5, 9] AS weeklyNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS id,
        [1, 10, 4] AS weeklyNumber
)
/*
┌─arrayReduce('sumForEach', groupArray(weeklyNumber))─┐
│ [3,15,13]                                           │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

---

*UPDATE*

```sql
SELECT sumForEach(arrayMap((x, y) -> (x / y), weeklyNumber, monthlyNumber)) AS result
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 AS id,
        [2, 5, 9] AS weeklyNumber,
        [20, 50, 90] AS monthlyNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS id,
        [1, 10, 4] AS weeklyNumber,
        [10, 100, 40] AS monthlyNumber
)
/*
┌─result────────┐
│ [0.2,0.2,0.2] │
└───────────────┘
*/
```